# reading files from memory instead of disk

Tags: java, xml, caching, java-io

I have a `Java` project with a huge set of XML files (>500). Reading this files at runtime leads to performance issues.

Is there an option to load all the XML files to RAM and read from there instead of the disk?

I know there are products like  [RamDisk](http://memory.dataram.com/products-and-services/software/ramdisk) but this one is a commercial tool.

Can I copy XML files to main memory and read from main memory using any existing Java API / libraries?

Comment: why not just store your data in a database that has caching.

Comment: Its a raw XML file, where users go and edit these XML files frequently. To store it in DB I have two options 1) store the raw XML ( which is inefficient for frequent edits). 2) convert the XML data to tables which is time consuming

Comment: Users come from different scenarios. Lets not deviate to type of App. Lets see if we can come up with some solution

Comment: @SurendranDuraisamy How large are the XML files approximately? How often are they being altered?

Comment: @padippist What platform are you running on - Windows? Unix?

Comment: @SurendranDuraisamy what you want to do with them in practice? Have you considered using an XML DB like those http://db-engines.com/en/ranking/native+xml+dbms?

Comment: 500 is not a 'huge set', and you can read millions of lines per second with `BufferedReader`. How are you reading these files? And is the time really going in I/O, or in XML parsing (which seems more likely)?

Answer (score 5):

I would first try memory mapped files, as provided by [`RandomAccessFile`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) and [`FileChannel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html) in standard java library. This way OS will be able to keep the frequently used file content in memory, effectively achieving what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can use **In-Memory databases** to store intermediate files (XML files). This will give the speed of using ram and db together.

For reference use the following links:

> http://www.mcobject.com/in_memory_database

Usage of H2 as in memory database:

> http://www.javatips.net/blog/2014/07/h2-in-memory-database-example

Answer (score 2):

Use `java.io.RandomAccessFile` class. It  behaves like a large array of bytes stored in the file system. Instances of this class support both reading and writing to a random access file.
Also  I would suggest using a `MemoryMappedFile`, to read the file directly from the disk instead of loading it in memory.

```
RandomAccessFile file = new RandomAccessFile("wiki.txt", "r");

FileChannel channel = file.getChannel();

MappedByteBuffer buf = channel.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 1024*50);
```

And then you can read the buffer as usual.

Comment: RandomAccessFile does not behave like a byte array.

Comment: documentation says that

Answer (score 0):

have you considered creating an object structure for these files and serializing them, java object serialization and deserialization is much faster than parsing an XML, this is again considering that these 500 or so XML files don't get modified between reads.

[here is an article](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072752/the-java-serialization-algorithm-revealed.html) which talks about serializing and deserializing.

if the concern is to load file content into memory, then consider `ByteArrayInputStream`, `ByteArrayOutputStream` classes maybe even use `ByteBuffer`, these can store the bytes in memory

Answer (score 0):

Java object serialization/deserialization is not faster than XML writing and parsing in general. When large numbers of objects are involved Java serialization/deserialization can actually be very inefficient, because it tracks each individual object (so that repeated references aren't serialized more than once). This is great for networks of objects, but for simple tree structures it adds a lot of overhead with no gains.

Your best approach is probably to just use a fast technique for processing the XML (such as `javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader`). Unless the files are huge, that 30-40 seconds time to load the XML files is way out of line - you're probably using an inefficient approach to processing the XML, such as loading them into a DOM. You can also try reading multiple files in parallel (such as by using Java 8 parallel Streams).

Comment: Dennis, I am reading lot of files in a single action which takes around 30-40 sec. Delay is not in processing the xml file. I am looking to reduce the disk read time, by loading all XML to RAM at the startup and reading them from RAM.

Comment: Are you certain the delay is really caused by disk access time? You can verify this by running a test with the files in a ramdisk drive. If disk access time is the issue a ramdisk is your best way of improving the speed. If a ramdisk is really out of the question for production, the next best thing is probably to put all the files into a single zip or gzip file and read the individual files from that. This approach would at least avoid some of the overhead of accessing all the files individually.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your main issue is large number of files and RAM is not an issue. Can you confirm?

Is it possible that you do a preprocessing step where you append all these files using some kind of separator and create a big file? This way you can increase the block size of your reads and avoid the performance penalty of disk seeks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about compressing the XML files and reading in those compressed XML files? Compressed XML could be as little as 3-5% the size of the original or better. You can uncompress it when it is visible to users and then store it compressed again for further reading.

Here is a library I found that might help:
[zip4j](http://www.lingala.net/zip4j/)

Answer (score 0):

It all depends, whether you read the data more than once or not.

Assuming we use some sort of Java-based-RamDisk (it would actually be some sort of Buffer or Byte-array).

Further assume the time to process the data takes less than reading from. So you have to read it at least one single time. So it would make no difference if you'd read it first from disk-to-memory and then process it from memory.

If you would read a file more than once, you could read all the files into memory (various options, Buffer, Byte-Arrays, custom FileSystem, ...).

In case processing takes longer than reading (which seems not to be the case), you could pre-fetch the files from disk using a separate thread - and process the data from memory using another thread.